# Show image in folder to Listview WindowsForm C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have an app created on WindowsForm C++, which i want to show some images in my folder to a Listview (listview1). It's compiled successfully but i cant make the images appear.

Here is my code:

```
ImageList ^ imgs = gcnew ImageList();
imgs->ImageSize = System::Drawing::Size(100, 100);
array<String^> ^paths = {};
paths = System::IO::Directory::GetFiles("Picture");
try
{
    for each (String ^ path in paths)
    {
        imgs->Images->Add(Image::FromFile(path));
    }
}
catch (Exception ^ e) {}
this->listView1->SmallImageList = imgs;
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: It is not enough code to show images.  You must also add items to the ListView and set their ImageIndex properties.

Comment: Ok i knew where the problem come from. My code was not enough. It runs as i expected now. Thank you so much!